# How do I activate Sora's Final Smash?

Tags: super-smash-flash-2

I'm having trouble pulling off Sora's Final Smash.  Everytime I get to the prompt button, I'm at a loss as to what to press.  Sometimes I mash random buttons, and it seems to work, until I get to the next prompt.

[image]

I've been trying a long time trying to pull this off. How do I pull of his Final Smash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use Sora's final smash, when the triangle appears, you press your special button once, do not mash buttons because that will cancel out the move.

Answer (score 2):

To activate Sora's final smash, You must press your heavy attack button (AKA The same button you pressed to activate it). Lets say you press O to activate the final smash. Press O again when the Triangle appears to attack again. This is the only way though. Any other button will cancel it out. Believe me, its hard. But just keep trying to get accurate hits. (Protip: I noticed this myself when trying to nail the buttons. When you see the red circle appear when you hit him, it means that the Triangle button is going to appear. Try to use that to get better accuracy when using his final smash! ^_^)

Answer (score 1):

Press O when you get to the prompt button, when Donald and Goofy come to help him.

Comment: Does it matter what keys I press? Or what keys I've configured previously?  I like to play my keys as WASD for movement, and rty45 for attacks/taunts.  Hitting the "o" key is kind of a stretch

Comment: I think you can check your key configurations in the settings...

Comment: So if O is my movement key, what do I press?

Comment: What do you mean by that? I'm trying to find out but for some reason the game isnt loading...as soon as I find out I will edit my answer

Comment: I know how to change key configs, I just don't know what to press

Comment: Like I said, O... maybe just as a test reset your config to default to see if it works?